# javascript - get img src

Tags: javascript, html, image, src

If I have an `img` in `index.html`:

```
<script src="script/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<img id="imgb" src="picture/banner1.jpg" border="0">
```

then in a separate file, such as `gallery.html`, I need to get the `src` element of the `img` in `index.html`.

I tried writing this function:

```
function imgbbs(){
    var x = document.getElementById('imgb').src;
    document.getElementById('imgbb').src = x;
}
```

Then try using it in `gallery.html`:

```
<script src="script/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<body onload="imgbbs()">
    <img id="imgbb" src="" border="0">
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. How can I get the `src` attribute of an `img` in a different file?

Comment: Unless you plan to make it dynamic at some point, `imgb` is  hard coded, this  means its not going to by dynamic,  just hard code it on the other page.

Comment: Is the gallery.html file in an iframe?

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this is to load a partial part of the `index` page using jquery it would be like this:

```
$( "#your_image_container_in_gallery.html" ).load( "index.html #imgb" );
```